# Como mudar a cor da borda?

Tags: java, swing

Como eu poderia alterar a cor da borda criada pelo BorderFactory?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BordaTitulo extends JDialog {

    public BordaTitulo() {
        setTitle("Teste Dialog");
        add(criaBorda());
        setSize(500, 320);        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent criaBorda() {
        JPanel painelPrincipal = new JPanel();
        painelPrincipal.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel painelBorda = new JPanel();
        painelBorda.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        painelBorda.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Teste"));

        painelBorda.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 70));         
        painelPrincipal.add(painelBorda);
        return painelPrincipal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BordaTitulo t = new BordaTitulo();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precisa de um pequeno "*workaround*" para funcionar.

Primeiro é preciso criar uma borda comum colorida, e depois uma `TitledBorder` passando a borda já criada junto com um titulo como parâmetro:

```
Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green);
TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lineBorder, "Teste");
painelBorda.setBorder(title);
```

Aplicado no seu código de exemplo, resulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser que o texto acompanhe a cor da borda, basta definir uma cor através do método [`setTitleColor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html#setTitleColor(java.awt.Color)) da classe `TitledBorder`:

```
Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green);
TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lineBorder, "Teste");
title.setTitleColor(Color.green);
painelBorda.setBorder(title);
```

Comment: ele alterou apenas o titulo, a linha que forma a borda continua padrão.

Comment: @Java ta usando nimbus como lookandfeel?

Comment: ta sem nenhum lookandfeel

Comment: @java agora sim, veja a edição.

Comment: agora sim ! Obrigado !